# React. Change pictures onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a page with many pictures. If you click on one picture, it should change. I tried to make it with toggling state but it works not the way I want: it changes all the photos if you click on just one.

Then I tried to use this code but it doesn't work at all (it doesn't even log)

```js
import bag1 from "../../img/bag1.jpg"

onClickHandler = (e) => {
        let src = (e.target.src || e.srcElement.src);
            if(src=={bag0}) {
            console.log("It works")
        }
    }


 render(){
        return(
      
            <div className="main">
              <img onClick={this.onClickHandler} src={bag0}/>
              </div>
        )

    }
```

Could you tell me, what's wrong here? Or do you know, how I can make another way?

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: `src=={bag0}` will always be `false`.

Comment: why it will be false?

Comment: `bag0` doesn't seem to change at any point. If you want the `src` to change you need to pass something that you control like a state variable or prop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example if this helps

```js
class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.defaultImage = 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/30-hardware-line-icons/64/Search-64.png';
  
    this.state = {
      selectedImage: this.defaultImage,
    }

    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler(e) {
    const src = e.target.src;
    if(src === this.defaultImage) {
        this.setState({ selectedImage: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-64.png' });
    }
  }

 render() {
     return(<div className="main">
     <img onClick={this.onClickHandler} src={this.state.selectedImage} />
              </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Tareq! I tried something similar. The problem here is that I need many pictures on the same page that would change (not at the same time) if you click on them.

Comment: Are looking for slider/carousel library ? try https://reactjsexample.com/tag/carousel/